# list of columns in common in two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm considering merge operations on dataframes each with a large number of columns. Don't want the result to have two columns with the same name. Am trying to view a list of column names in common between the two frames:

```
import pandas as pd

a = [{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 2},{'A': 2,  'B': 4, 'C': 3, 'D': 9}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
b = [{'F': 0,  'M': 4,  'B': 2,  'C': 8 },{'F': 2,  'M': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 9}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)

df1.columns
>> Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
df2.columns
>> Index(['B', 'C', 'F', 'M'], dtype='object')

(df2.columns).isin(df1.columns)
>> array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

How do I operate that NumPy boolean array on the Index object so it just gives back a list of the columns in common?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) or [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
a = np.intersect1d(df2.columns, df1.columns)
print (a)
['B' 'C']

a = df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)
print (a)
Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Alternative syntax for the latter option:

```
df1.columns & df2.columns
```

Comment: how could i get the opposite? the columns which are not in both dataframes?@jezrael, in this case A,D,FM

Comment: @raffa_sa - use `df2.columns.symmetric_difference(df1.columns)`, [`symmetric_difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.symmetric_difference.html)