# Intersection of two or more DataFrame columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the intersect of three dataframes, however the `pd.intersect1d` does not like to use three dataframes.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('BCDE'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('CDEF'))

inclusive_list = np.intersect1d(df1.columns, df2.columns, df3.columns)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The `inclusive_list` should only include column names C & D. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: Not going to hammer because the error makes this a bit different, but the question is very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539195/list-of-columns-in-common-in-two-pandas-dataframes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Why your current approach doesn't work***:

[`intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) does not take `N` arrays, it only compares 2.

> `numpy.intersect1d(ar1, ar2, assume_unique=False, return_indices=False)`

You can see from the definition that you are passing the third array as the `assume_unique` parameter, and since you are treating an array like a single boolean, you receive a `ValueError`.

---

You can extend the functionality of `intersect1d` to work on `N` arrays using `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(np.intersect1d, (df1.columns, df2.columns, df3.columns))
```

```
array(['C', 'D'], dtype=object)
```

---

***A better approach***

However, the easiest approach is to just use intersection on the `Index` object:

```
df1.columns & df2.columns & df3.columns
```

```
Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can using `concat`

```
pd.concat([df1.head(1),df2.head(1),df3.head(1)],join='inner').columns
Out[81]: Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inclusive_list = np.intersect1d(np.intersect1d(df1.columns, df2.columns), df3.columns)
```

Note that the arguments passed to np.intersect1d (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) are expected to be two arrays (*ar1 and ar2*).

Passing 3 arrays means that the assume_unique variable within the function is being set as an array (expected to be a bool).

You can also use simple native python set methods if you don't want to use numpy

```
inclusive_list = set(df1.columns).intersection(set(df2.columns)).intersection(set(df3.columns))
```

Comment: You don't need the conversion to set.  An `Index` object is already implemented as an "ordered, sliceable set", and you can use those operations on it already.