# Concatenate two dataframes and drop duplicates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For `df2` which only has data in the year of `2019`:

```
  type  year  value
0    a  2019     13
1    b  2019      5
2    c  2019      5
3    d  2019     20
```

`df1` has multiple years data:

```
  type  year  value
0    a  2015     12
1    a  2016      2
2    a  2019      3
3    b  2018     50
4    b  2019     10
5    c  2017      1
6    c  2016      5
7    c  2019      8
```

I need to concatenate them together while replacing `df2`'s values in `2019` with the values from `df1`'s same year.

The expected result will like this:

```
  type  date  value
0    a  2015     12
1    a  2016      2
2    b  2018     50
3    c  2017      1
4    c  2016      5
5    a  2019     13
6    b  2019      5
7    c  2019      5
8    d  2019     20
```

The result from `pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort =False)`, which clearly have multiple `value`s in `year` of 2019 for one `type`. How should I improve the code? Thank you.

```
   type  date  value
0     a  2019     13
1     b  2019      5
2     c  2019      5
3     d  2019     20
4     a  2015     12
5     a  2016      2
6     a  2019      3
7     b  2018     50
8     b  2019     10
9     c  2017      1
10    c  2016      5
11    c  2019      8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for get last rows per `type` and `date` after `concat`.

Solution working if `type` and `date` pairs are unique in both DataFrames.

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort =False)
        .drop_duplicates(['type','date'], keep='last'))
```

Comment: Does `keep='last'` mean that `value`s from `df1` will be taken instead of `df2`? What if I write `df = (pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True, sort =False).drop_duplicates(['type','date'], keep='last'))`

Comment: @ahbon - It means it get last value of concanecated rows, so here from `df2` if exist, if not exist from df1.

Comment: point - after pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort =False) the values from df1 are the top 4 rows so keep='last' keeps the original values and doesn't updates with the new values..

Comment: @iamklaus - yes, just see it. If test OP output from `pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort =False)` it means `df1 is df2` and `df2 is df1`, just edit question.

Comment: `I need to concatenate them together while replacing df2's values in 2019 with the values from df1's same year.`.. best would be to change the names :) +1

Comment: Sorry, if `df1` and `df2` don't have same columns, for example, if `df1` has more columns `a, b, c`, it seems doesn't work out. I have tried with `df = (pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort =False)
        .drop_duplicates(['type','date', 'a', `b`, `c`], keep='last'))`, duplicates rows remain. Should I change something else?

Comment: Can you change `df = (pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, sort =False) .drop_duplicates(['type','date', 'a', b, c], keep='last'))` to `df = (pd.concat([df1, df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)], ignore_index=True, sort =False) .drop_duplicates(['type','date', 'a', b, c], keep='last'))` - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48539234/2901002)